# How to create new columns using .loc syntax?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of names of columns (`cols`) that exist in one dataframe.

I want to insert columns by those names in another dataframe.

So I am using a `for` loop to iterate the list and create the columns one by one:

```
cols = ['DEPTID', 'ACCOUNT', 'JRNL LINE DESCRIPTION', 'JRNL DATE', 'BASE AMOUNT', 'FOREIGN CURRENCY', 'FOREIGN AMOUNT', 'JRNL SOURCE']
for col in cols:
    # "summary" and "obiee" are dataframes
    summary.loc[obiee['mapid'], col] = obiee[col].tolist()
```

I would like to get rid of the `for` loop, however.

So I have tried multiple column assignment using the `.loc` syntax:

```
cols = ['DEPTID', 'ACCOUNT', 'JRNL LINE DESCRIPTION', 'JRNL DATE', 'BASE AMOUNT', 'FOREIGN CURRENCY', 'FOREIGN AMOUNT', 'JRNL SOURCE']
summary.loc[obiee['mapid'], cols] = obiee[cols]
```

but Pandas will throw an error:

```
KeyError: "['DEPTID' 'ACCOUNT' 'JRNL LINE DESCRIPTION' 'JRNL DATE' 'BASE AMOUNT'\n 'FOREIGN CURRENCY' 'FOREIGN AMOUNT' 'JRNL SOURCE'] not in index"
```

Is it not possible with this syntax? How can I do this otherwise?

Comment: I don't think you can create new columns with the `.loc` approach. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc says it is label based so those columns must be there. What you could do is just pre-allocate those columns and you're good. `for col in cols: summary[col] = None` or you can use the `assign` property. As long as the columns exist you should be able to use `.loc`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy: Thanks! Regarding: "I don't think you can create new columns with the .loc approach": note that I am able to do this in my example with a single column label, but not with a list of labels (hence my question).

Comment: For many columns, even intuitively thinking, you want to `merge`, `concat` or `join` data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `join`

You can create a new dataframe and then `join`.  From your problem description and sample code, `'mapid'` represents index values in the `summary` dataframe.  `join` is made to merge on index.  So by setting `obiee`'s index to `'mapid'` then taking the the appropriate columns, we can just use `join`.

```
summary.join(obiee.set_index('mapid')[cols])
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a dataFrame df1 .. with some columns...

And you want those in a df2 ... all you need to do is just equate them as show below

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
   ....:                      'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
   ....:                      'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
   ....:                      'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
   ....:                      'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
   ....:                      'F' : 'foo' })
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'G' : 1.,
   ....:                      'H' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
   ....:                      'I' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
   ....:                      'J' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
   ....:                      'K' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
   ....:                      'L' : 'foo' })
df2['G'],df2['F'] = df1['G'],df1['H']
```